# ActionResult HttpPost need to access value

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am using MVC C#
Say I have the following ActionResult:

```
    public ActionResult Create(string location) 
    { 
      ... 
      View()  
    }
```

I need to use location primary in the [httppost]

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(Employee employee) 
    { 
      ...
     // I need to access the value of location here but I dont' have access to the View  
    }
```

What is the best way of getting the value of location. I can create a viewmodel and pass that value to the View and then retreive it in the  [HttpPost ]but I do not have access to the View as it is restricted.

Comment: I cannot modify anything within the view. The View was created. We were told not to modify it in any form

Comment: @NatePet - is this homework?  Sounds like the kind of arbitrary restriction that homework typically requires.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a number of methods to pass data between controller methods in mvc. One of them is by using `TempData`. 
You can save `location` in your GET-method

```
public ActionResult Create(string location) 
{ 
  TempData["location"] = location;
  ...
  View()  
}
```

and then retrieve it in your POST-method

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(Employee employee) 
{ 
  var location = TempData["location"];
  ...
}
```

Although, using a viewmodel would be more preferrable.

Comment: Why not just use a session variable

Comment: You can use a session variable, however `TempData` is used only for redirects. TempData is also a more secure way of passing data because sessions may be "stolen" from the user.